# If enough people start using a word contextually wrong when does the word's meaning change?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Example

Say some percent of the English speaking population started using the word "sky" to replace the meaning of "cloud", at what percent would you be wrong in using the word "sky" to refer to the sky.

Comment: This question has no definite answer when asked this way. Have you got an actual example which isn't as exaggerated as the one you're giving here?

Comment: Related: [If enough people say “supposably” instead of “supposedly”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/if-enough-people-say-supposably-instead-of-supposedly), [Will grammar errors become “correct” after enough people use them for long enough?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3448/will-grammar-errors-become-correct-after-enough-people-use-them-for-long-enoug), [When does a mistake become standard usage?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/9314/8732), [Descriptivism and widespread misspelling](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3723/8732)

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but unfortunately, as it is worded, it is much too broad and philosophical to meet the guidelines in the FAQ.

Comment: Related: [What are the criteria to adopt new words into English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11455)

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to get back and give my example, which was chili. I know chili as a seed pod, everyone else I've met thinks it's a stew of some kind. Sorry about the ambiguity of my question. Thanks for all the comments/answer anyways.

Comment: I don't think there's any concrete answer, like "once over 60% of the population have used this word over a period of at least 5 years". Changes in the language just come to be accepted over time. Like, several hundred years ago "professor" meant "someone who professes a particular idea or belief", e.g. a believer in a given religion. Today it means "a teacher at a college". A few decades ago, "gay" meant happy and care-free; today it means "homosexual". Etc. Changes in meaning just ... come to be accepted over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Irene in saying this question can be given no definite answer, as it seems (by the way its phrased) to ignore factors such as the context, location, period and culture (etc.) in which the word is used, which would (over time) contribute to the accepted understanding of the word.

Furthermore, words don't become "wrong" or "right" overnight, or when they reach a certain "acceptance percentage" with the population. Words generally fade/evolve with time and adopt totally new meanings or simply fall away. Once again, it is also important to note that they don't fall away or change globally, but normally in a small community that may or may not spread that words new meaning to other places. And even when the overwhelming majority may understand a word by a new meaning, it may still be considered "correct" to understand the word by its old meaning.

One (admittedly poor) example of this is use of the word "Incredible" which is normally taken to be akin to "amazing" or "awesome", but is also taken (a bit more archaically) to mean "not believable". Both meanings are correct, even though one (or both) may fall away in the future.

The question may be more viable with more information, but as it stands, I agree with Irene's comment.

Comment: I can give a good, close example.  Take the word Irregardless. (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irregardless)

Comment: @RHL Ye gods! Say it ain't so!