# A word that means "apparently" but with less conviction?

Tags: word-choice

Example:

> The circular window was **apparently** made to match the shape of the
>   sun.

Here *apparently* expresses doubt, but with a certain level of conviction: that was the intent of the person who designed the window.  Is there a word similar to *apparently* but with less level of conviction? Almost as if the conclusion were a rough guess? Or something that the speaker made up?

Comment: "It seems the circular window was made to match the shape of the sun."

Comment: @Elian - I don't think OP is asking for the difference between *apparently and seemingly*.

Comment: @Elian I think Elian gave an answer with the comment.

Comment: @Rathony Okay, I'll retract my close vote and post "seemingly" as a possible answer. :-)

Comment: @Elian Nothing better than seemingly. Go ahead and I will vote.

Comment: @Jano - "it seems to me" "it would seem to be the case that" "it seemed to us" and so on are popular phrases for this.

Comment: If you got the information from somewhere else, vs thinking of it on your own, "ostensibly" would fit.

Comment: The simplest way to suggest doubt about the possibility being put forward might be to use _perhaps_ in place of _apparently_.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Seemingly** is what you're looking for.

> **Seemingly vs. apparently**
>
> Apparently:
>
> - Is used when you have read or been told something, although you are not certain it is true.
>     *Apparently it's going to rain today.*
> - Is used when the situation is different than what you thought it was.
>     *You know I told you Alice's party was on the 13th? Well, I just saw her and it's apparently on the 14th. How do you like that?*
>
> Seemingly:
>
> - Appearing to be something, especially when this is not true.
>     *He remains confident and seemingly untroubled by his recent problems.*
> - According to the facts that you know.
>     *The factory closure is seemingly inevitable.*
>
> ([**Quora**](https://www.quora.com/English-language/How-do-I-use-evidently-apparently-probably-perhaps-maybe-possibly-certainly-and-seemingly-in-speech))

Comment: Seemingly is indeed the best fit here.

Comment: Jano - you often say "It ***would seem that*** the circular window was made to match the shape of the sun.".  And note - a really common one is: ***It would seem to me...***  *"It seemed to us that the window was made to fit the sun"  "It would seem to me that the window was sized to fit the sun"* and so on.

Comment: I could substitute "apparently" for "seemingly" in the second-to-last example.

Comment: You could also say: "**It appears** that the circular window was made to match the shape of the sun." I do not know if this is a regional thing, but it is very common in the American English I am familiar with.

Answer (score 26):

[**Supposedly**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/supposedly):

> used to show that you do not ​believe that something you have been told is ​true:
>   *Well, the ​tickets are supposedly in the ​mail.* ( -- Cambridge Dictionaries Online)

Comment: I think "seemingly" is a better fit here. "Supposedly" implies that the speaker heard this from another person but doubts whether it's true. "Seemingly" implies the speaker came to this conclusion himself, which is closer to what the OP seemingly wanted.

Comment: Reading the question again, I don't disagree. It wasn't clear to me what led the speaker to think the window *might* have been made to match the shape of the sun. If he read the suggestion in a guide book but wasn't convinced, then 'supposedly' would be correct. If it was a comparison he'd tentatively drawn himself, then 'seemingly' (or another word) might be better. The last sentence of the question suggests that the OP was thinking of the latter case. Some clarification from him would be welcome.

Comment: Interesting how the very words we are discussing are relevant to the original question. It's like some answers could eat their own tail :)

Answer (score 11):

***[Ostensibly](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ostensibly)***:

> "As appears or is stated to be true, ***though not necessarily so***"

'Apparently' as defined in the OED:

> "As far as one knows or can see"

...only *implies* the converse.

So in my mind 'ostensibly' has a larger measure of doubt.

Comment: Does 'ostensibly'  convey a weaker sense compared to 'apparently'?

Comment: To me yes, a little ...  But that's just me :)  I did look up 'apparently' in the dictionary also: "as far as one knows or can see" (OED), which as you can see, only *implies* the converse. Because of that I felt my intuition was correct.

Comment: Does *ostensibly* mean the same thing as *apparently*? To me it is a near-synonym of *superficially*.

Comment: @WS2 see updated answer and comment above :)

Comment: @LamarLatrell But I still tend to think *ostensibly* introduces the idea of there being more than one reason - an *ostensible* one and a real underlying one which for some devious reason is unspoken.

Comment: ***Ostensibly***: http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ostensibly

Comment: @Josh61 I like that one Josh. Ostensibly to buy ice-creams but really to chat up the girl behind the counter. A very apt description of *ostensibly*.

Comment: I think that the main connotation of 'ostensibly' is that something is done  "on purpose"  to appear different from what it is..somethning that does not really match with the way the  shape of the window was made.

Comment: Take it up with Oxford chaps :)

Comment: Also, why hasn't the same reasoning been applied to 'supposedly' and the apparent synonyms?

Comment: I think "ostensibly" is a lot like "supposedly" but with the added connotation that the person that told you might have been trying to deceive you.

Comment: (Obviously) I'm going with the OED definition - but it seems there are two camps, those who think it goes too far (deception/devious), and those who think it's too much of a synonym for 'apparent' itself. Cant have it both ways! Perhaps this deserves its own Q&A ?  :)

Answer (score 11):

**Possibly**

This might seem a strange fit, but it does convey less certainty and conviction.

"Apparently she's gone to the movies."
"Possibly she's gone to the movies."

"Apparently he stole it."
"Possibly he stole it."

Comment: Possibly is inclusive of a range of cases where there is a *lot* less certainty than I think the OP (possibly) had in mind :)

Answer (score 11):

I could go with ***presumably***, which goes beyond "this may be what they were trying to do, but I don't know if they achieved it" to cast doubt even upon the inferred intent itself.

> The circular window was **presumably** made to match the shape of the sun.

Comment: That seems like an odd interpretation of "presumably". "Presumably" means that you made a presumption, i.e. that you've assumed something with evidence. That's a great fit for the question, I'm just not sure about your explanation. Maybe I've misunderstood your meaning?

Answer (score 5):

It changes the sentence form, but **suggests** or **implies**.

> The circular shape of the window suggests it was made to match the shape of the sun.

Comment: I like "suggests" better than "seemingly".  To my mind, it makes it clear that the speaker is stating an independent conclusion.

Comment: This makes sense, but you have to mangle the sentence to use the word. It doesn't slide in there nicely as a synonym would.

Answer (score 4):

If some irony is acceptable, I like ***allegedly***.

Answer (score 1):

The choice depends on the level of skepticism or sarcasm you want to inject...

In order of preference I would offer:

- ostensibly
- putatively
- purportedly
- allegedly

Comment: Welcome to the English Language & Usage Stack Exchange!  We typically prefer some level of detail as to *why* you are suggesting words, such as a definition.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way to express this:

> The circular window *might have been* made to match the shape of the sun.

Bonus: eliminates an adverb.

Comment: You don't like adverbs?

Comment: @DCShannon Google "avoid adverbs".

Answer (score 1):

**Likely**  would indicate that the speaker is making a guess but is fairly certain about it.

Answer (score 0):

I might use ***purportedly***, were it for something recent, but if it concerned something 400 years old then: *the window, **according to legend**, was made to fit the shape of the sun*.

Answer (score 0):

The circular window **gave the illusion** of being made to match the shape of the sun.

> Definition of "illusion" from MW: a misleading image presented to the
> vision; perception of something objectively existing in such a way as
> to cause misinterpretation of its actual nature; something that looks
> or seems different from what it is, something that is false or not
> real but that seems to be true or real.
>
> Example: Everyone knows that vertical stripes can be very slimming and give the illusion of height.

You may also replace *illusion* by "*impression*".

Comment: Personally, I prefer impression over illusion for this approach.

Comment: "gave the impression" is a good answer that fits perfectly, whereas gave the illusion implies a level of certainty in it in fact being the other way.

Gave the impression > a neutral comment that the window would appear to be made to match the shape of the sun.  Gave> the illusion it does give that impression, but that impression is probably misleading.

Comment: "gave the illusion" is wrong enough to warrant a downvote, but "gave the impression" is close to an upvote.. I'll just leave it be

Answer (score 0):

How about [on the face of it](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-the-face-of-it)?

> The circular window, on the face of it, was made to match the shape of
>   the sun.

Answer (score -1):

I'll put forth the more rarely used ***supposably***, which is the adverb form of *supposable*.

> :  capable of being supposed :  conceivable
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supposable)</sub>

It connotes less conviction because it sounds like a made-up word (arguably because it was implied to be made-up when used in the TV show [*Friends*](http://every-friends-joke.blogspot.com/2012/09/because-she-pronounces-it-supposably.html)).

Comment: That's an incorrect usage of the word supposably. See [Difference between “supposedly” and “supposably”](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/62354/70061)

Comment: @DCShannon: Doesn't the provided definition say otherwise, since *conceivably* is a synonym?

Comment: The difference is very subtle. It's generally best to just avoid using 'supposably'.